# Using a matrix table to look up a value in a data.frame

Tags: r, matrix

I have a df that looks like this:

```
 head(df)
 MATCHID COMPETITION            TEAM1              TEAM2 GOALS1 GOALS2 RESULT  EXPG1 EXPG2     DATUM     TIJD POINTS  DIFF
 1 1696873  Pro League   Standard Liège Sporting Charleroi      3      0  TEAM1  1.57  0.61 25-7-2014 18:30:00    0.4  0.96
 2 1696883  Pro League Waasland-Beveren        Club Brugge      0      2  TEAM2  1.29  1.18 26-7-2014 16:00:00    0.0  0.11
```

What I would like to do is to create a new column where I can put the distance between TEAM1 and TEAM2. I therefore created a matrix called "clubs" that looks like this:

```
           Arsenal Aston.Villa Burnley Chelsea Crystal.Palace Everton Hull.City Leicester.City Liverpool Manchester.City Manchester.United Newcastle.United
Arsenal        ""      "114.6"     "234.3" "10.1"  "12.5"         "209.3"  "182.4"   "98.5"         "208.8"   "208.2"         "199.6"           "273.7"         
Aston Villa    "114.6" ""          "122.6" "125.6" "153.2"        "97.8"  "137"     "41.5"         "97"      "96.4"          "87.8"            "205.1"         
Burnley        "234.3" "122.6"     ""      "245.2" "272.8"        "50.8"  "113"     "145.2"        "53.9"    "28.9"          "34.7"            "115.8"         
Chelsea        "10.1"  "125.6"     "245.2" ""      "9.7"          "221.1" "189.1"   "104.7"        "220.5"   "219.9"         "211.3"           "280.4"         
crystal Palace "12.5"  "153.2"     "272.8" "9.7"   ""             "229.5" "203.7"   "113.1"        "228.9"   "228.3"         "219.7"           "294.9"         
Everton        "209.3" "97.8"      "50.8"  "221.1" "229.5"        ""      "128.5"   "122.8"        "0.9"
```

This works cause if I try clubs("Arsenal","Aston.Villa") I get 114.6

Now I want to fill the column "Distance" for the whole df by using this formula:

```
 get_distance <- function(matrix,x,y){matrix[x,y]}

 df$distance <- sapply(clubs_names, get_distance(clubs_names, df$TEAM1, df$TEAM2))
```

But that doesnt do the trick. I get the following error:

```
Error in matrix[x, y] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Any thoughts on where I go wrong?

These are my dput values:

```
dput(head(clubs))
structure(c("", "114.6", "234.3", "10.1", "12.5", "209.3", "114.6",  
"", "122.6", "125.6", "153.2", "97.8", "234.3", "122.6", "", 
"245.2", "272.8", "50.8", "10.1", "125.6", "245.2", "", "9.7", 
"221.1", "12.5", "153.2", "272.8", "9.7", "", "229.5", "209.3", 
"97.8", "50.8", "221.1", "229.5", "", "182.4", "137", "113", 
"189.1", "203.7", "128.5", "98.5", "41.5", "145.2", "104.7", 
"113.1", "122.8", "208.8", "97", "53.9", "220.5", "228.9", "0.9", 
"208.2", "96.4", "28.9", "219.9", "228.3", "38", "199.6", "87.8", 
"34.7", "211.3", "219.7", "34.7", "273.7", "205.1", "115.8", 
"280.4", "294.9", "172.6", "7.8", "120.7", "240.3", "4.2", "12.6", 
"217.9", "90.3", "142.3", "261.8", "77.9", "85.3", "239.4", "154.6", 
"44.1", "83", "167.5", "175.9", "60.6", "267.9", "199.4", "112.3", 
"274.7", "289.2", "169.7", "199", "155", "263.1", "186.6", "195.1", 
"179.4", "4.8", "115", "234.6", "18.9", "27.3", "212.2", "121.4", 
"4.2", "118.4", "131.1", "139.5", "96", "9.6", "132.7", "250.6", 
"13.1", "15.3", "229.9"), .Dim = c(6L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(
c("Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Burnley", "Chelsea", "crystal Palace", 
"Everton"), c("Arsenal", "Aston.Villa", "Burnley", "Chelsea", 
"Crystal.Palace", "Everton", "Hull.City", "Leicester.City", 
"Liverpool", "Manchester.City", "Manchester.United", "Newcastle.United", 
"Queens.Park.Rangers", "Southampton", "Stoke.City", "Sunderland", 
"Swansea.City", "Tottenham.Hotspur", "West.Bromwich.Albion", 
"West.Ham.United")))


 > dput(head(df))
structure(list(X = 1:6, MATCHID = c(1696873L, 1696883L, 1696879L, 
1696881L, 1696877L, 1696871L), COMPETITION = structure(c(11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("2. Bundesliga", "Bundesliga", 
"Championship", "Eredivisie", "Ligue 1", "Ligue 2", "Premier League", 
"Premiership", "Primeira Liga", "Primera División", "Pro League", 
"Segunda División", "Serie A", "Serie B", "Süper Lig"), class = "factor"), 
TEAM1 = structure(c(248L, 276L, 153L, 281L, 167L, 14L), .Label = c("?stanbul   Ba?ak?ehir", 
"1860 München", "Aalen", "Aberdeen", "Académica", "ADO Den Haag", 
"AFC Bournemouth", "Ajaccio", "Ajax", "Akhisar Belediyespor", 
"Albacete", "Alcorcón", "Almería", "Anderlecht", "Angers", 
"Arles", "Arouca", "Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Atalanta", 
"Athletic Club", "Atlético Madrid", "Augsburg", "Auxerre", 
"Avellino", "AZ", "Bal?kesirspor", "Barcelona", "Barcelona II", 
"Bari 1908", "Bastia", "Bayer Leverkusen", "Bayern München", 
"Be?ikta?", "Belenenses", "Benfica", "Birmingham City", "Blackburn Rovers", 
"Blackpool", "Boavista", "Bochum", "Bologna", "Bolton Wanderers", 
"Bordeaux", "Borussia Dortmund", "Borussia M'gladbach", "Brentford", 
"Brescia", "Brest", "Brighton & Hove Albion", "Burnley", 
"Bursaspor", "Caen", "Cagliari", "Cambuur", "Cardiff City", 
"Carpi", "Catania", "Celta de Vigo", "Celtic", "Cercle Brugge", 
"Cesena", "Charlton Athletic", "Châteauroux", "Chelsea", 
"Chievo", "Cittadella", "Clermont", "Club Brugge", "Córdoba", 
"Créteil", "Crotone", "Crystal Palace", "Darmstadt 98", "Deportivo Alavés", 
"Deportivo La Coruña", "Derby County", "Dijon", "Dordrecht", 
"Dundee", "Dundee United", "Eibar", "Eintracht Braunschweig", 
"Eintracht Frankfurt", "Elche", "Empoli", "Erzgebirge Aue", 
"Eski?ehirspor", "Espanyol", "Estoril", "Everton", "Evian TG", 
"Excelsior", "Fenerbahçe", "Feyenoord", "Fiorentina", "Fortuna Düsseldorf", 
"Freiburg", "Frosinone", "FSV Frankfurt", "Fulham", "Galatasaray", 
"Gazélec Ajaccio", "Gaziantepspor", "Gençlerbirli?i", "Genk", 
"Genoa", "Gent", "Getafe", "Gil Vicente", "Girona", "Go Ahead Eagles", 
"Granada", "Greuther Fürth", "Groningen", "Guingamp", "Hamburger SV", 
"Hamilton Academical", "Hannover 96", "Heerenveen", "Heidenheim", 
"Hellas Verona", "Heracles", "Hertha BSC", "Hoffenheim", 
"Huddersfield Town", "Hull City", "Ingolstadt", "Internazionale", 
"Inverness CT", "Ipswich Town", "Juventus", "Kaiserslautern", 
"Karabükspor", "Karlsruher SC", "Kas?mpa?a", "Kayseri Erciyesspor", 
"Kilmarnock", "Köln", "Konyaspor", "Kortrijk", "KV Oostende", 
"Las Palmas", "Latina", "Laval", "Lazio", "Le Havre", "Leeds United", 
"Leganés", "Leicester City", "Lens", "Levante", "Lierse", 
"Lille", "Liverpool", "Livorno", "Llagostera", "Lokeren", 
"Lorient", "Lugo", "Mainz 05", "Málaga", "Mallorca", "Manchester City", 
"Manchester United", "Marítimo", "Mechelen", "Mersin ?dmanyurdu", 
"Metz", "Middlesbrough", "Milan", "Millwall", "Mirandés", 
"Modena", "Monaco", "Montpellier", "Moreirense", "Motherwell", 
"Mouscron-Péruwelz", "NAC Breda", "Nacional", "Nancy", "Nantes", 
"Napoli", "Newcastle United", "Nice", "Nîmes", "Niort", "Norwich City", 
"Nottingham Forest", "Numancia", "Nürnberg", "Olympique Lyonnais", 
"Olympique Marseille", "Orléans", "Osasuna", "Paços de Ferreira", 
"Paderborn", "Palermo", "Parma", "Partick Thistle", "PEC Zwolle", 
"Penafiel", "Perugia", "Pescara", "Ponferradina", "Porto", 
"Pro Vercelli", "PSG", "PSV", "Queens Park Rangers", "Racing Santander", 
"Rayo Vallecano", "RB Leipzig", "Reading", "Real Betis", 
"Real Madrid", "Real Sociedad", "Real Valladolid", "Real Zaragoza", 
"Recreativo Huelva", "Reims", "Rennes", "Rio Ave", "Rizespor", 
"Roma", "Ross County", "Rotherham United", "Sabadell", "Saint-Étienne", 
"Sampdoria", "Sandhausen", "Sassuolo", "Schalke 04", "Sevilla", 
"Sheffield Wednesday", "Sivasspor", "Sochaux", "Southampton", 
"Spezia", "Sporting Braga", "Sporting Charleroi", "Sporting CP", 
"Sporting Gijón", "St. Johnstone", "St. Mirren", "St. Pauli", 
"Standard Liège", "Stoke City", "Stuttgart", "Sunderland", 
"Swansea City", "Tenerife", "Ternana", "Torino", "Tottenham Hotspur", 
"Toulouse", "Tours", "Trabzonspor", "Trapani", "Troyes", 
"Twente", "Udinese", "Union Berlin", "Utrecht", "Valencia", 
"Valenciennes", "Varese", "Vicenza", "Villarreal", "Virtus Entella", 
"Virtus Lanciano", "Vitesse", "Vitória Guimarães", "Vitória Setúbal", 
"Waasland-Beveren", "Watford", "Werder Bremen", "West Bromwich Albion", 
"West Ham United", "Westerlo", "Wigan Athletic", "Willem II", 
"Wolfsburg", "Wolverhampton Wanderers", "Zulte-Waregem"), class = "factor"), 
TEAM2 = structure(c(242L, 69L, 142L, 158L, 106L, 179L), .Label = c("?stanbul   Ba?ak?ehir", 
"1860 München", "Aalen", "Aberdeen", "Académica", "ADO Den Haag", 
"AFC Bournemouth", "Ajaccio", "Ajax", "Akhisar Belediyespor", 
"Albacete", "Alcorcón", "Almería", "Anderlecht", "Angers", 
"Arles", "Arouca", "Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Atalanta", 
"Athletic Club", "Atlético Madrid", "Augsburg", "Auxerre", 
"Avellino", "AZ", "Bal?kesirspor", "Barcelona", "Barcelona II", 
"Bari 1908", "Bastia", "Bayer Leverkusen", "Bayern München", 
"Be?ikta?", "Belenenses", "Benfica", "Birmingham City", "Blackburn Rovers", 
"Blackpool", "Boavista", "Bochum", "Bologna", "Bolton Wanderers", 
"Bordeaux", "Borussia Dortmund", "Borussia M'gladbach", "Brentford", 
"Brescia", "Brest", "Brighton & Hove Albion", "Burnley", 
"Bursaspor", "Caen", "Cagliari", "Cambuur", "Cardiff City", 
"Carpi", "Catania", "Celta de Vigo", "Celtic", "Cercle Brugge", 
"Cesena", "Charlton Athletic", "Châteauroux", "Chelsea", 
"Chievo", "Cittadella", "Clermont", "Club Brugge", "Córdoba", 
"Créteil", "Crotone", "Crystal Palace", "Darmstadt 98", "Deportivo Alavés", 
"Deportivo La Coruña", "Derby County", "Dijon", "Dordrecht", 
"Dundee", "Dundee United", "Eibar", "Eintracht Braunschweig", 
"Eintracht Frankfurt", "Elche", "Empoli", "Erzgebirge Aue", 
"Eski?ehirspor", "Espanyol", "Estoril", "Everton", "Evian TG", 
"Excelsior", "Fenerbahçe", "Feyenoord", "Fiorentina", "Fortuna Düsseldorf", 
"Freiburg", "Frosinone", "FSV Frankfurt", "Fulham", "Galatasaray", 
"Gazélec Ajaccio", "Gaziantepspor", "Gençlerbirli?i", "Genk", 
"Genoa", "Gent", "Getafe", "Gil Vicente", "Girona", "Go Ahead Eagles", 
"Granada", "Greuther Fürth", "Groningen", "Guingamp", "Hamburger SV", 
"Hamilton Academical", "Hannover 96", "Heerenveen", "Heidenheim", 
"Hellas Verona", "Heracles", "Hertha BSC", "Hoffenheim", 
"Huddersfield Town", "Hull City", "Ingolstadt", "Internazionale", 
"Inverness CT", "Ipswich Town", "Juventus", "Kaiserslautern", 
"Karabükspor", "Karlsruher SC", "Kas?mpa?a", "Kayseri Erciyesspor", 
"Kilmarnock", "Köln", "Konyaspor", "Kortrijk", "KV Oostende", 
"Las Palmas", "Latina", "Laval", "Lazio", "Le Havre", "Leeds United", 
"Leganés", "Leicester City", "Lens", "Levante", "Lierse", 
"Lille", "Liverpool", "Livorno", "Llagostera", "Lokeren", 
"Lorient", "Lugo", "Mainz 05", "Málaga", "Mallorca", "Manchester City", 
"Manchester United", "Marítimo", "Mechelen", "Mersin ?dmanyurdu", 
"Metz", "Middlesbrough", "Milan", "Millwall", "Mirandés", 
"Modena", "Monaco", "Montpellier", "Moreirense", "Motherwell", 
"Mouscron-Péruwelz", "NAC Breda", "Nacional", "Nancy", "Nantes", 
"Napoli", "Newcastle United", "Nice", "Nîmes", "Niort", "Norwich City", 
"Nottingham Forest", "Numancia", "Nürnberg", "Olympique Lyonnais", 
"Olympique Marseille", "Orléans", "Osasuna", "Paços de Ferreira", 
"Paderborn", "Palermo", "Parma", "Partick Thistle", "PEC Zwolle", 
"Penafiel", "Perugia", "Pescara", "Ponferradina", "Porto", 
"Pro Vercelli", "PSG", "PSV", "Queens Park Rangers", "Racing Santander", 
"Rayo Vallecano", "RB Leipzig", "Reading", "Real Betis", 
"Real Madrid", "Real Sociedad", "Real Valladolid", "Real Zaragoza", 
"Recreativo Huelva", "Reims", "Rennes", "Rio Ave", "Rizespor", 
"Roma", "Ross County", "Rotherham United", "Sabadell", "Saint-Étienne", 
"Sampdoria", "Sandhausen", "Sassuolo", "Schalke 04", "Sevilla", 
"Sheffield Wednesday", "Sivasspor", "Sochaux", "Southampton", 
"Spezia", "Sporting Braga", "Sporting Charleroi", "Sporting CP", 
"Sporting Gijón", "St. Johnstone", "St. Mirren", "St. Pauli", 
"Standard Liège", "Stoke City", "Stuttgart", "Sunderland", 
"Swansea City", "Tenerife", "Ternana", "Torino", "Tottenham Hotspur", 
"Toulouse", "Tours", "Trabzonspor", "Trapani", "Troyes", 
"Twente", "Udinese", "Union Berlin", "Utrecht", "Valencia", 
"Valenciennes", "Varese", "Vicenza", "Villarreal", "Virtus Entella", 
"Virtus Lanciano", "Vitesse", "Vitória Guimarães", "Vitória Setúbal", 
"Waasland-Beveren", "Watford", "Werder Bremen", "West Bromwich Albion", 
"West Ham United", "Westerlo", "Wigan Athletic", "Willem II", 
"Wolfsburg", "Wolverhampton Wanderers", "Zulte-Waregem"), class = "factor"), 
GOALS1 = c(3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L), GOALS2 = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L), RESULT = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("TEAM1", 
"TEAM2"), class = "factor"), EXPG1 = c(1.57, 1.29, 1.03, 
1.76, 1.6, 1.27), EXPG2 = c(0.61, 1.18, 1.04, 1.24, 1.23, 
0.62), DATUM = structure(c(136L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 150L, 
150L), .Label = c("1-1-2015", "1-10-2014", "1-11-2014", "1-12-2014", 
"1-2-2015", "1-3-2015", "1-4-2015", "1-5-2015", "1-8-2014", 
"1-9-2014", "10-1-2015", "10-11-2014", "10-2-2015", "10-3-2015", 
"10-4-2015", "10-5-2015", "10-8-2014", "11-1-2015", "11-10-2014", 
"11-2-2015", "11-3-2015", "11-4-2015", "11-5-2015", "11-8-2014", 
"12-1-2015", "12-10-2014", "12-12-2014", "12-4-2015", "12-5-2015", 
"12-9-2014", "13-12-2014", "13-2-2015", "13-3-2015", "13-4-2015", 
"13-5-2015", "13-8-2014", "13-9-2014", "14-12-2014", "14-2-2015", 
"14-3-2015", "14-4-2015", "14-9-2014", "15-11-2014", "15-12-2014", 
"15-2-2015", "15-3-2015", "15-4-2015", "15-5-2015", "15-8-2014", 
"15-9-2014", "16-1-2015", "16-11-2014", "16-12-2014", "16-2-2015", 
"16-3-2015", "16-5-2015", "16-8-2014", "16-9-2014", "17-1-2015", 
"17-10-2014", "17-12-2014", "17-2-2015", "17-3-2015", "17-4-2015", 
"17-5-2015", "17-8-2014", "17-9-2014", "18-1-2015", "18-10-2014", 
"18-12-2014", "18-3-2015", "18-4-2015", "18-5-2015", "18-8-2014", 
"19-1-2015", "19-10-2014", "19-12-2014", "19-4-2015", "19-5-2015", 
"19-8-2014", "19-9-2014", "2-11-2014", "2-12-2014", "2-2-2015", 
"2-3-2015", "2-4-2015", "2-5-2015", "2-8-2014", "20-1-2015", 
"20-10-2014", "20-12-2014", "20-2-2015", "20-3-2015", "20-4-2015", 
"20-5-2015", "20-8-2014", "20-9-2014", "21-1-2015", "21-10-2014", 
"21-11-2014", "21-12-2014", "21-2-2015", "21-3-2015", "21-4-2015", 
"21-5-2015", "21-9-2014", "22-11-2014", "22-12-2014", "22-2-2015", 
"22-3-2015", "22-4-2015", "22-5-2015", "22-8-2014", "22-9-2014", 
"23-1-2015", "23-11-2014", "23-2-2015", "23-3-2015", "23-5-2015", 
"23-8-2014", "23-9-2014", "24-1-2015", "24-10-2014", "24-11-2014", 
"24-12-2014", "24-2-2015", "24-4-2015", "24-5-2015", "24-8-2014", 
"24-9-2014", "25-1-2015", "25-10-2014", "25-2-2015", "25-4-2015", 
"25-5-2015", "25-7-2014", "25-8-2014", "25-9-2014", "26-1-2015", 
"26-10-2014", "26-12-2014", "26-4-2015", "26-7-2014", "26-9-2014", 
"27-1-2015", "27-10-2014", "27-12-2014", "27-2-2015", "27-4-2015", 
"27-7-2014", "27-9-2014", "28-10-2014", "28-11-2014", "28-12-2014", 
"28-2-2015", "28-3-2015", "28-4-2015", "28-9-2014", "29-10-2014", 
"29-11-2014", "29-12-2014", "29-3-2015", "29-4-2015", "29-5-2015", 
"29-8-2014", "29-9-2014", "3-1-2015", "3-10-2014", "3-11-2014", 
"3-12-2014", "3-2-2015", "3-3-2015", "3-4-2015", "3-5-2015", 
"3-8-2014", "30-1-2015", "30-10-2014", "30-11-2014", "30-12-2014", 
"30-4-2015", "30-5-2015", "30-8-2014", "30-9-2014", "31-1-2015", 
"31-10-2014", "31-5-2015", "31-8-2014", "4-1-2015", "4-10-2014", 
"4-11-2014", "4-12-2014", "4-2-2015", "4-3-2015", "4-4-2015", 
"4-5-2015", "4-8-2014", "5-1-2015", "5-10-2014", "5-11-2014", 
"5-12-2014", "5-2-2015", "5-4-2015", "5-5-2015", "6-1-2015", 
"6-10-2014", "6-12-2014", "6-2-2015", "6-3-2015", "6-4-2015", 
"6-5-2015", "6-9-2014", "7-1-2015", "7-11-2014", "7-12-2014", 
"7-2-2015", "7-3-2015", "7-4-2015", "7-6-2015", "7-9-2014", 
"8-11-2014", "8-12-2014", "8-2-2015", "8-3-2015", "8-4-2015", 
"8-5-2015", "8-8-2014", "9-1-2015", "9-11-2014", "9-2-2015", 
"9-3-2015", "9-4-2015", "9-5-2015", "9-8-2014"), class = "factor"), 
TIJD = structure(c(35L, 25L, 33L, 33L, 9L, 25L), .Label = c("10:00:00", 
"10:30:00", "11:00:00", "11:15:00", "11:30:00", "11:45:00", 
"12:00:00", "12:15:00", "12:30:00", "12:45:00", "13:00:00", 
"13:05:00", "13:20:00", "13:30:00", "13:45:00", "14:00:00", 
"14:05:00", "14:15:00", "14:30:00", "14:45:00", "15:00:00", 
"15:15:00", "15:30:00", "15:45:00", "16:00:00", "16:15:00", 
"16:30:00", "16:45:00", "17:00:00", "17:15:00", "17:30:00", 
"17:45:00", "18:00:00", "18:15:00", "18:30:00", "18:45:00", 
"18:50:00", "18:55:00", "19:00:00", "19:15:00", "19:30:00", 
"19:45:00", "20:00:00", "20:15:00", "20:30:00", "20:45:00", 
"21:00:00", "21:15:00", "21:30:00", "22:00:00"), class = "factor"), 
POINTS = c(0.4, 0, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3), DIFF = c(0.96, 0.11, 
-0.01, 0.52, 0.37, 0.65)), .Names = c("X", "MATCHID", "COMPETITION", 
"TEAM1", "TEAM2", "GOALS1", "GOALS2", "RESULT", "EXPG1", "EXPG2", 
"DATUM", "TIJD", "POINTS", "DIFF"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class =  "data.frame")
```

Comment: your part matrix[x,y] expects only two values... (and not two lists of values). And your `clubs`-matrix has character values in it, is that intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df$distance <- df2[cbind(df$team1, df$team2)]
```

Explanation:

You can subset using a matrix like `cbind(myrows, mycolumns)` as we did in the solution. From the help for `` ?`[` ``:

> A third form of indexing is via a numeric matrix with the one column
>   for each dimension: each row of the index matrix then selects a single
>   element of the array, and the result is a vector.

Reproducible Example:

```
set.seed(1130)
df <- data.frame(id=1:4, team1=LETTERS[1:4], team2=LETTERS[5:8])
df2 <- matrix(sample(16), nrow=4, dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:4], LETTERS[5:8]))

df$distance <- df2[cbind(df$team1, df$team2)]
df
#   id team1 team2 distance
# 1  1     A     E        2
# 2  2     B     F       16
# 3  3     C     G        7
# 4  4     D     H        9
```

*addendum* - If you would like to use your original approach, try:

```
get_distance <- function(mat,x,y) mat[x,y]
mapply(get_distance, mat=list(df2), x=df$team1, y=df$team2)
#[1]  2 16  7  9
```

Comment: Dear @Pierre Lafortune, thanks for your elaborated answer. When I try this with my matrix I get:Error in mat[x, y] : subscript out of bounds. Any thoughts where this might be coming from?

Comment: The best way to tell is to post your `dput(head(clubs))` and `dput(head(df))`. You have something in your data that is creating the error. (Add it to your question).

Comment: just added it to my question

Comment: Thank you. Your team columns are not `character` class, they are `factor`. You need to convert the columns to character with `as.character`.

Comment: Try adding `df[c('TEAM1', 'TEAM2')] <- lapply(df[c('TEAM1', 'TEAM2')], as.character)`

Comment: Hm... I added it and get have > class(df$TEAM1)
[1] "character"
> class(df$TEAM2)
[1] "character" now... But I still get the error out of bounds

Comment: Your names have to be exact matches. For example, your row names have spaces but your column names have dot separations.

Comment: To test if all of the teams match, the output for `setdiff(df$TEAM1, dimnames(clubs)[[1]])` should be `character(0)` meaning all of the names in the team column are present in the matrix row names. And the same for `setdiff(df$TEAM2, dimnames(clubs)[[2]])`. There should not be any teams that show up in those tests.

Comment: thanks a lot! Had a lot small typo: "crystal palace" instead of "Cystal palace"... Devil is in the details!